# How to use Redux toolkit dispatch in Next.js SSG or SSR?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, ssg

I'm confused a long time to fix my issues on the use Hook like `useDispatch` in `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` .
I'm using `redux-toolkit` for managing states and also use Next.js , but when to use (`useDispatch`) in my SSG function I got the error

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component.

I also found a solution to fix the issue, that uses `redux-next-wrapper`. But I want to know is there another way to fix my issue except `redux-next-wrapper`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nextjs, the best way to avoid potential errors is to use next-redux-wrapper . It may seems a little confusing at first but soon you will figure it out. I have a boiler plate for next-redux-wrapper on my github with 3 simple reducers to match different situations, feel free to change it to suite your needs : https://github.com/vahidkk/My-customized-Redux-Wrapper-for-Next.js-with-3-reducers

Comment: this link could not be found

Comment: Sorry, forgot to make it public . Check it out again .

Answer (score 0):

i know its too late too answer this question,
but it may help others.

in my recent nextjs app, i needed to have internationalization and all of the locales comes from backend. i wanted to have locales in application without passing it to child elements.

as you know, you can store your variable in class statically, and when you change the variable, it will change in the whole program.

so i decided to store my vars like this:

```
export class SSRStore {
    static locales = {};
}
```

and change them it my page components:

```
export default function Home({ myLocales }) {
    SSRStore.locales = myLocales;
        
    return (
        <MainLayout>
        </MainLayout>
    )
 }
    
 export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    return {
        props: {
            myLocales: {...}
        }
    }
 }
```

whenever i change the data on SSR, it will get effected in whole program without having SEO issues.

its not `redux`, but its better than using `next-redux-wrapper` that the latest publish was 8 months ago.